# using ubuntu 12.04 LTS but also have Windows 7 on same computer- how to I wipe windows?

Tags: 12.04, windows

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using the windows installer, but now would just like to remove windows altogether. What is the best way to do this? Is there a way to do this other than using a CD/CVD or USB?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well use Wubi Migrating tool, here you have documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi

Remember to plug the charger If you are using a laptop.